# Is it possible to create a html file using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to create a html file and save it to a directory using JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use purely Javascript or Jquery to save to the client machine however you can use Javascript and Flash 10 to save small files 3-4kb to the client machine.....go to this page for an example: http://downloadify.info/ and check out the demo.

Answer (score 3):

No, Javascript(client side) can't write to files

You can't if you want to create a file on the client machine. If you want to create a file on the server, the backend code can do that.

Comment: If you take a look over to http://www.tiddlywiki.org you can see how it's done nevertheless @Svetlozar :)
But in case you're referring to scripts which originate from a webserver you have to pass several security-warnings to allow the page to access the local disk.

Comment: @Kosi2801 IIRC, Tiddlywiki stores the data in cookies, not as a file in the filesystem.

Comment: @david-dorward no, you'd be wrong. when you access the file from a file:// path it updates that file when you save. You have to click ok on a security dialog the first time, but it works seamlessly after that. No cookies though.

Answer (score 2):

No, you won't be able to do that with JavaScript alone.

JavaScript runs in a client browser and saving files to local disk is a security threat.

From [JavaScript Security](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/JavaScript-Security/)

**JavaScript Security Models**

> The modern JavaScript security model
>   is based upon Java. In theory,
>   downloaded scripts are run by default
>   in a restricted “sandbox” environment
>   that isolates them from the rest of
>   the operating system. Scripts are
>   permitted access only to data in the
>   current document or closely related
>   documents (generally those from the
>   same site as the current document). No
>   access is granted to the local file
>   system, the memory space of other
>   running programs, or the operating
>   system’s networking layer. Containment
>   of this kind is designed to prevent
>   malfunctioning or malicious scripts
>   from wreaking havoc in the user’s
>   environment. The reality of the
>   situation, however, is that often
>   scripts are not contained as neatly as
>   one would hope. There are numerous
>   ways that a script can exercise power
>   beyond what you might expect, both by
>   design and by accident.
>
> The fundamental premise of browsers’
>   security models is that there is no
>   reason to trust randomly encountered
>   code such as that found on Web pages,
>   so JavaScript should be executed as if
>   it were hostile. Exceptions are made
>   for certain kinds of code, such as
>   that which comes from a trusted
>   source. Such code is allowed extended
>   capabilities, sometimes with the
>   consent of the user but often without
>   requiring explicit consent. In
>   addition, scripts can gain access to
>   otherwise privileged information in
>   other browser windows when the pages
>   come from related domains.

Comment: It appears that the OP wants to save the file on the client side. A server side language would not help.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is no. Javascript runs in a sandbox environment and you cannot save files on user computer. You could save it to the server though by sending it through an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

you can design html pages using javascript but not specifically using JQuery.

Checkout **["TIBCO GENERAL INTERFACE"](http://developer.tibco.com/gi/product_resources37.jsp?tab=#)**

Download and open sample project.

TIBCO GI is javascript based IDE to design html pages.

**http://developer.tibco.com/gi/product_resources37.jsp?tab=#**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Document, that may contain a complete HTML file using javascript's document Object.

But you can't save it as HTML file using Javascript.